# Change PHP path in OS X terminal to XAMPP PHP

Tags: php, macos, terminal, bash

I just installed Composer on OS X 10.8 and am now trying to use it to install something else and it turns out my terminal is running php 5.3... In XAMPP I have 5.5, so I would like to just use that version in Terminal as well. I tried creating a .bash_profile in my home directory with

```
export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-5.5.11/bin:$PATH
```

but that wouldn't work; `which php` still returns /usr/bin/php. What am I missing here? Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you solve it? If so, tell us how :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my working Environment Path

```
export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Remember to wrap the path with double quotes and also close all terminal before checking the php version using

```
php -v or which php
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using a bash shell, then changing the bash_profile won't make a difference. bash apparently wasn't always the default, so on my mac, I am using .tcsh. I don't know why it uses one over the other, it has just always been that way (been upgrading macs since OS X 10.0). So on mine I have a .tcshrc file which operates like the bash_profile. In there I have

```
alias php /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.7/bin/php
```

which you would obviously have to adjust to your own path and version, but you get the point.

Comment: Could you please add more details to your answer? Where is that .tcshrc file? How do I open it in order to add that alias? Otherwise, here is my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37364433/1883256)

Comment: `/Users/<username>` or `cd ~`